# Install SCIP solver on Python3.5 Numberjack (OSX)

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, solver, scip

I am learning Constraint Programming in Python and, for the solving of the problems, I am supposed to use the SCIP solver. I have installed the Numberjack standard package from Github witch includes Mistral, Mistral2, Toulbar2, MipWrapper, SatWrapper, MiniSat and Walksat solvers.

Running my code I got the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/angelocoelho/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/Numberjack/__init__.py", line 910, in load
    lib = __import__(solverstring, fromlist=[solverspkg])
ImportError: No module named 'Numberjack.solvers.SCIP'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "grafosdefluxos.py", line 42, in <module>
    solver = model.load('SCIP')
  File "/Users/angelocoelho/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/Numberjack/__init__.py", line 915, in load
    solvername)
ImportError: ERROR: Failed during import, wrong module name? (SCIP)
```

I already ran `make` in '**scipoptsuite-3.1.0**' and in '**scip-3.2.1**', installed **Numberjack-master**'s 'setup.py' and tried this:

`python setup.py -solver SCIP`

witch returned the error

```
Error: the solver 'SCIP' is not known, please use one of: Mistral, SatWrapper, Toulbar2, Walksat, MipWrapper, MiniSat, Mistral2
```

I have the SCIP folders alongside and inside the Numberjack folders.
I read and ran all the commands in the README and INSTALL files on how I could get this solver configured but I couldn't get it right.
How can I get SCIP available to solve the problems in Numberjack?

Comment: Numberjack's setup routine seems to be broken. Running `python setup.py build` will always search for CPLEX - even if another solver is specified. see https://github.com/eomahony/Numberjack/issues/47 for updates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After talking to the assistant teacher I got the answer for this problem.

The folder where Numberjack/SCIP was being installed was not the one it was supposed to be, therefore it was not really included in the solver list. After completing the `python setup.py build` and `python setup.py install` installation I ran `python setup.py build -solver SCIP` and the terminal feedback stated

`Successfully built solver interfaces for MipWrapper, SCIP`

But the jupyter notebook didn't recognize the solver.

What solution should work having Anaconda (python3.5) already installed:

1. Download [Numberjack](https://github.com/eomahony/Numberjack#scip) (file "Numberjack-master.zip") and unpack it.
2. Download [SCIP](http://scip.zib.de/download.php?fname=scipoptsuite-3.1.0.tgz) and copy the downloaded file, `scipoptsuite-3.1.0.tgz`. Paste it **inside** Numberjack-master unpacked directory. The path of it should be `~/Downloads/Numberjack-master/scipoptsuite-3.1.0.tgz`.
3. In terminal run `cd ~/Downloads/Numberjack-master` (or your Numberjack-master directory path).
4. Then run  `python3.5 setup.py install --user`.

   In my case Jupyter was looking for the solvers in
   `~/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/Numberjack/` and they were
   not being installed there so, instead of using `python`, I used `python3.5` since my Anaconda was the Python 3.5 package.

Answer (score 1):

Why is there a `scip-3.2.1` directory? The SCIP Opt Suite 3.1.0 contains SCIP 3.1.0. You need to make sure to run all setup and make commands *exactly* as stated on the [Numberjack install page](https://github.com/eomahony/Numberjack#scip).

Comment: I did everything stated in Numberjack install page. Using the python setup.py install command made it be installed in a directory the jupyter noteboook was not searching for. Thank you.